# Get contents of password variable in response file

Tags: install4j

I'm evaluating install4j. The installer I'm trying to create uses a passwort text field. The value of this field should be written to the response var file as encoded value. Additional the installer must allow two installation paths:

- a normal path ("advanced") that allows the user to see every screen and check/enter every value - using this path, the password field works fine.
- a simple path that should use all values of a former installation that was succesful, to allow the user to start an update installation without seeing all screens.

Using the simple path (without showing the screen that contains the password field) it seems that at installation time only the encoded variable ("passwordField".encoded) is available but not the "real" password variable. **Is there a chance to get the "real" password variable without showing the screen that contains this variable** - maybe by using some kind of "decoding method"?

Thank you very much for your help!

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another password component with the same variable to a screen that is shown on the simple path and set its visibility expression to "false". Then that invisible component will update the variable with the decoded value.